# If $|f(x)+g(x)|=|f(x)|+|g(x)|$ and $|f(x)|=\lambda |g(x)|$ do we have $f(x)=\lambda g(x)$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Suppose we have two complex valued functions $f$ and $g$ and we know that $|f(x)+g(x)|=|f(x)|+|g(x)|$ and $|f(x)|=\lambda |g(x)|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$ and some constant $\lambda$.

Is it true that $f(x)=\lambda g(x)$?

My guess would be that this is indeed correct since the triangle (in)equality tells us $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ lie on a straight line in the plane. But I am quite embarrassed that I cannot find a way to find a formal proof for that fact. Does anyone have nice argument for that?

Comment: A formal proof for the equality case in the triangle inequality ?

Comment: A formal proof for $f(x)=\alpha g(x)$ in case that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix any $x \in \mathbb{C}$. If $f(x) = 0$, then $g(x) = 0$ (from $|f(x)|= \alpha |g(x)|$) and we get $f(x) = \alpha g(x)$ easily. Otherwise, assume $f(x) \ne 0$ (and so $g(x) \ne 0$). Since we have $|f(x) + g(x)| = |f(x)|+|g(x)|$, there is some $\lambda > 0$ such that $f(x) = \lambda g(x)$. Taking modulus we get

$$|f(x)| = \lambda |g(x)| = \alpha |g(x)|$$

So $\lambda = \alpha$ and we also get $f(x) = \alpha g(x)$.

Comment: you should fix some notations.

Comment: @A.F.23 : What notations exactly do you think need fixing ?

Comment: Read 5xum's answer or my answer.

Comment: @A.F.23 : You need to be more specific.

Comment: the lambda which you introduce is not a positive number, it's a positive real function.

Comment: @A.F.23 : Well, $x$ is a fixed number in my proof (as stated in the first sentence), so $\lambda$ is just a plain number. Actually, I fixed $x$ to **emphasize** the fact that the whole proof is just about complex numbers, functions are mostly irrelevant here.

Comment: But I think the hole proof is just about: if the division of absolute values of such two function is constant then the division of  values of them is constant too. For two number always we have $a=\lambda b$ :) I still think your proof is right but uses bad notation.

Comment: @A.F.23 : But the point here is that $\lambda$ is real and positive, while $a$ and $b$ are complex.

Answer (score 3):

First I answer this question: when triangle inequality becomes equality? I work on inner product spaces over complex field:
$$\|a+b\|=\|a\|+\|b\|
\\\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+2\|a\|\|b\|
\\(a+b)\cdot (a+b)=a\cdot a+b\cdot b+2\|a\|\|b\|
\\a\cdot a+b\cdot b+2a\cdot b=a\cdot a+b\cdot b+2\|a\|\|b\|
\\ \Rightarrow a\cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|
\\\Rightarrow |a\cdot b|=\|a\|\|b\|$$
so we have equality case in Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and it is well known that equality occurs in Cauchy–Schwarz inequality iff two vectors are dependent so we have:
$${\large b}=\alpha {\large a}$$ 
and also:
$$a\cdot b=\|a\|\|b\|\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\overline \alpha \|a\|^2=\|a\|\|b\|\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,\overline \alpha={\|b\| \over \|a\|}$$
that means $\alpha$ has no imaginary part and precisely belongs to $\Bbb R^+$.
Now I return to your problem. In your conditions we have:
$$f(x)=\alpha (x)g(x)\,\,\,\,\text {so we have}\,\,\,\,\ \|f(x)\|=\alpha (x)\|g(x)\|$$ 
notice that from my first prove $\alpha$ depends on vectors. And If we have:
$$\|f(x)\|=\lambda \|g(x)\|$$
Then $\alpha (x)=\lambda$ (except when $g(x)$ is zero but that case is trivial and OK) which means $\alpha (x)$ must be a constant and finally we have:
$$f(x)=\lambda g(x)$$

Comment: The first condition is definitely< not sufficient, as it is fulfilled for every pair of non-negative functions, even if they are not constant multiples of each other, say $e^x$ and $e^{2x}$. Note that the absolute value is not a norm on the space of functions; rather it maps functions to other functions.

Comment: I corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first equality tells you that, for every $x\in \mathbb C$, there exists some constant $0<\lambda(x)\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = \lambda(x) g(x)$ (you can see that this is so even if one of them is $0$, since the other must be $0$ as well).

The second equality tells you that, for every $x\in\mathbb C$, there exists some constant $\mu(x)\in \mathbb C$ such that $|\mu(x)| = 1$ and that $f(x) = \mu(x)\alpha g(x)$

Using the two facts gives you $\mu(x)\alpha = \lambda(x)$ for every $x$, meaning that, since $\alpha, \lambda(x)\in\mathbb R^+$, you know that $\mu(x) \in\mathbb R^+$ and $|\mu(x)|=1$, meaning that $\mu=1$.

Comment: So we have $f(x) = \alpha g(x)$ as $\mu=1$? Thus the answer is yes?

Comment: @Hetebrij Yes, the "no" in the beginning was a mistake.

Comment: In your first sentence, why $\lambda (x) \in\mathbb R^+$ ?

Comment: @A.F. Because in any normed space, $||x+y|| = ||x|| + ||y||$ if and only if $x=\lambda y$ for $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Please read my proof, I prove your assertion just in inner product spaces over real numbers field. can you prove it for other field or give me a link? also I think it is wrong.

Comment: @A.F.23 Well, actually, my answer is correct. Only my comment is wrong. What I should have written is "because if the norm is induced from an inner product, then...". If the norm is induced from an inner product, then equality is only possible if the vectors have the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** If $\left|z+1\right|=\left|z\right|+1$, then $z=\left|z\right|$.

**Proof:** Subtracting the squares of equal quantities, we get
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\overbrace{(z+1)(\overline{z+1})}^{\left|z+1\right|^2}-\overbrace{(z\overline{z}+2\left|z\right|+1)\vphantom{\overline{1}}}^{\left(\left|z\right|+1\right)^2}\\
&=z+\overline{z}-2\left|z\right|\\
&=2\operatorname{Re}(z)-2\left|z\right|
\end{align}
$$
That is, $\operatorname{Re}(z)=\left|z\right|$, which means that $\operatorname{Re}\left(\large\frac{z}{\left|z\right|}\right)=1$.

Since $\large\frac{z}{\left|z\right|}$ is on the unit circle and only one point on the unit circle has real part equal to $1$, we must have ${\large\frac{z}{\left|z\right|}}=1$. That is, $z=\left|z\right|$.

$\square$

---

From the first equation, we have
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}+1\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|+1
$$
which the Lemma says means $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$.

Incorporating the second equation, we have
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=\lambda
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
f(x)=\lambda g(x)
$$